# Spring security using service does not autowirte the dependencies and gives null pointer exception

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am having trouble with my UserService. It does not recognize the autowired dependencies that are defined within it. I tried both using Autowired annotation directly on the variable and on the constructor separately. `knowledgbaseDao` is null in the `loadUserByUsername`. On startup, constructors of this class is called 3 times. Each creates different objects. First one is created using the default empty constructor. Other two is created using the autowired constructor and assigns `knowledgebaseDao` the correct class. When userservice is called from login page it uses the first UserService class and a null pointer exception is thrown. Here is my code :

```
@Component("userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    private KnowledgeBaseDao knowledgeBaseDao;

    public UserService(){
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserService(KnowledgeBaseDao knowledgeBaseDao) {
        this.knowledgeBaseDao = knowledgeBaseDao;
        }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.info("UserDetails Database Service : " + login);

        // check user exists in database
        User user = knowledgeBaseDao.findUserByEmail(login);
        if (user == null) {
            logger.warn("User({}) does not exist in system", login);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("There is no user with this username.");
        }

        boolean containsLoginRole = checkLoginRole(user);

        if (!containsLoginRole) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Access denied.");
        }

        if ((user.getStatus() == null || user.getStatus() == 0)) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User is not confirmed");
        }

        //boolean enabled = user.getStatus() == AccountStatus.ACTIVE;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        if (user.getLoginTryCount() != null && user.getLoginTryCount() >= 3) {
            accountNonLocked = false;
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, this.getAuthorities(user.getRoleId()));
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roleList) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : roleList) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Long roleId) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Constants.ROLE_NAME(roleId.intValue())));

        return authorities;
    }

    private boolean checkLoginRole(User user) {
        if (user.getRoleId() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (user.getRoleId() == Constants.ROLE_ADMIN
                || user.getRoleId() == Constants.ROLE_MODERATOR
                || user.getRoleId() == Constants.ROLE_USER) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE :

Here is the security.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Disabled Security for Static Resources -->
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
    <http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>

    <beans:bean id="shaPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="256"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.service.UserService"/>

    <!-- Ajax Aware Handler -->
    <beans:bean id="authEntryPoint"
                class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.spring.AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                scope="singleton">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/knowledge-base"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint"
          pattern="/knowledge-base/**"
          use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

        <custom-filter position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="loginFilter"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/knowledge-base" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                logout-url="/knowledgeBase/j_spring_security_logout"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/knowledge-base/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/knowledge-base/memory"
                       access="hasRole('ADMIN') || hasRole('MODERATOR') || hasRole('USER')"/>

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/knowledge-base/error/403"/>
        <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/knowledge-base/error/sessionExpired"/>
    </http>

    <!-- ************************** -->

    <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <password-encoder ref="shaPasswordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/knowledgeBase/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:bean class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.spring.AuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:bean class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.spring.AuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- ************************** -->


</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can you please try to remove the no-arg constructor? Also, if you leave just the one with the DAO, the autowired annotation is not mandatory, as per the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html). Alternatively, you can [specify in the XML the constructor to use](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-injection) (scroll a few lines to `<constructor-arg ref="bar"/>`), but since the no-arg one is not doing anything, just get rid of the bloatware.

Comment: it is called when instantiating the application. it is the interesting thing actually. when i remove it i get an exception at the startup. also when i debug and put breakpoints in these constructors, i see that first it enters to no-arg constructor and next, two times it enters into the other constructor and autowires the dependency. but when it comes to loadbyusername method, when it is called, it uses the first class with no knowledgebasedao defined.

Comment: What exception are you getting? Did you add `<constructor-arg ref="knowledgeBaseDao`> in your service definition from the XML? It's a bit weird without having a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce it, as you have your service defined as both `@Component` & an XML definition, so there may be multiple instances, maybe in different context? Difficult to say without seeing the entire setup...

Answer (score 1):

I have a project like this in gitHub : [link](https://github.com/azzabihaythem/newTest/blob/9143fcc87de3ea2f4e3e6558623c200958620a9d/PFE.test01/src/main/java/com/haythem/service/Impl/CustomUserDetailsService.java)

you should use `@Autowired` with your Dao :

```
@Autowired
private KnowledgeBaseDao knowledgeBaseDao;
```

dont forget to scan the dao package

Comment: I tried this before, but no way. Also, I've been using knowledgebasedao before. the problem is with the way userservice is initialized. it is separately initialized from other spring components and when it is, its not autowiring the injected dependencies

Comment: userservice  is a singleton it will be initialized only one time, even if the service is used by many other services,so the problem is not from other components

Comment: do you have security xml file

Comment: yes in [security xml] (https://github.com/azzabihaythem/newTest/blob/master/PFE.test01/src/main/resources/META-INF/security-context.xml)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by explicitly defining required beans in the sequrity xml and removing any autowired annotation from the userservice class:

```
<beans:bean id="maxIdCalculator" class="com.gsu.common.util.MaxIdCalculator">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="knowledgeBaseDao" class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.repository.KnowledgeBaseDao">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="kbDataSource"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="maxIdCalculator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userService" class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.service.UserService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="knowledgeBaseDao"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: is the same like @Autowired but with xml